# importing azure automl environement with a registerd model

Tags: python, azure, anaconda, automl

I am trying to use an azure automl generated model in my code, for supplementray test purposes (so I do not want to deploy it for the moment. I use the following code to load the model:

```
import joblib
from azureml.core.model import Model
from azureml.core import Workspace
import os
import pickle

ws = Workspace.from_config()
path=Model.get_model_path('my_automl_model', version=1, _workspace=ws)
model_path = os.path.join(path, 'model.pkl')
model = joblib.load(model_path)
```

When I run this code, I obtain the following error:

```
/anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/util.py:873: UserWarning: [W094] Model 'en_core_web_sm' (2.1.0) specifies an under-constrained spaCy version requirement: >=2.1.0. This can lead to compatibility problems with older versions, or as new spaCy versions are released, because the model may say it's compatible when it's not. Consider changing the "spacy_version" in your meta.json to a version range, with a lower and upper pin. For example: >=3.4.0,<3.5.0
  warnings.warn(warn_msg)
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/azureuser/....ipynb Cellule 4 in <cell line: 11>()
      9 model_path = os.path.join(path, 'model.pkl')
     10 print(os.stat(model_path))
---> 11 model = joblib.load(model_path)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py:605, in load(filename, mmap_mode)
    599             if isinstance(fobj, _basestring):
    600                 # if the returned file object is a string, this means we
    601                 # try to load a pickle file generated with an version of
    602                 # Joblib so we load it with joblib compatibility function.
    603                 return load_compatibility(fobj)
--> 605             obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
    607 return obj

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py:529, in _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
    527 obj = None
    528 try:
--> 529     obj = unpickler.load()
    530     if unpickler.compat_mode:
    531         warnings.warn("The file '%s' has been generated with a "
    532                       "joblib version less than 0.10. "
    533                       "Please regenerate this pickle file."
    534                       % filename,
...
    679     return config.from_disk(
    680         config_path, overrides=overrides, interpolate=interpolate
    681     )

OSError: [E053] Could not read config file from /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/en_core_web_sm/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0/config.cfg
```

Inside the automl model folder, I have the following files:

[image: mlflow model]

I think that this error is because I am running on pyton 3.8.5 where as the model is generated on python 3.7.9 (as indicated in the conda.yaml file):

````
channels:
- anaconda
- conda-forge
- pytorch
dependencies:
- python=3.7.9
- pip=20.2.4
- pip:
  - mlflow
  - https://aka.ms/automl-resources/packages/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz
  - regex==2022.8.17
  - fsspec==2022.8.2
  - certifi==2022.6.15
  - pytz==2022.2.1
  - setuptools==63.4.1
  - azureml-dataprep-native==38.0.0
  - cryptography==37.0.4
  - pyzmq==23.2.1
  - attrs==22.1.0
  - pyopenssl==22.0.0
  - contextlib2==21.6.0
  - packaging==21.3
  - azure-mgmt-resource==21.1.0
  - pip==20.2.4
  - gunicorn==20.1.0
  - azure-mgmt-storage==20.0.0
  - azure-storage-blob==12.13.0
  - azure-storage-queue==12.4.0
  - azure-mgmt-keyvault==10.1.0
  - humanfriendly==10.0
  - azure-mgmt-containerregistry==10.0.0
  - pillow==9.2.0
  - ipython==7.34.0
  - jupyter-client==7.3.5
  - click==7.1.2
  - thinc==7.0.8
  - ipykernel==6.6.0
  - tornado==6.2
  - pyarrow==6.0.0
  - pyyaml==6.0
  - importlib-resources==5.9.0
  - psutil==5.9.0
  - traitlets==5.3.0
  - cachetools==5.2.0
  - decorator==5.1.1
  - docker==5.0.3
  - smmap==5.0.0
  - py-cpuinfo==5.0.0
  - tqdm==4.64.1
  - fonttools==4.37.1
  - jsonschema==4.15.0
  - importlib-metadata==4.12.0
  - jupyter-core==4.11.1
  - rsa==4.9
  - pexpect==4.8.0
  - typing-extensions==4.3.0
  - azureml-dataprep==4.2.2
  - ephem==4.1.3
  - gitdb==4.0.9
  - bcrypt==4.0.0
  - protobuf==3.20.1
  - gensim==3.8.3
  - zipp==3.8.1
  - configparser==3.7.4
  - h5py==3.7.0
  - matplotlib==3.5.3
  - secretstorage==3.3.3
  - idna==3.3
  - lightgbm==3.2.1
  - oauthlib==3.2.0
  - gitpython==3.1.27
  - dotnetcore2==3.1.23
  - mpi4py==3.1.3
  - prompt-toolkit==3.0.31
  - flask-cors==3.0.10
  - pyparsing==3.0.9
  - boto==2.49.0
  - distributed==2.30.1
  - dask==2.30.0
  - requests==2.28.1
  - pycparser==2.21
  - pystan==2.19.1.1
  - semver==2.13.0
  - pygments==2.13.0
  - jinja2==2.11.2
  - google-auth==2.11.0
  - paramiko==2.11.0
  - google-api-core==2.10.0
  - python-dateutil==2.8.2
  - azureml-dataprep-rslex==2.8.1
  - portalocker==2.5.1
  - liac-arff==2.5.0
  - networkx==2.5
  - bokeh==2.4.3
  - sortedcontainers==2.4.0
  - pyjwt==2.4.0
  - convertdate==2.3.2
  - mkl-service==2.3.0
  - werkzeug==2.2.2
  - cloudpickle==2.2.0
  - jsonpickle==2.2.0
  - zict==2.2.0
  - spacy==2.1.8
  - flask==2.1.3
  - itsdangerous==2.1.2
  - charset-normalizer==2.1.1
  - en-core-web-sm==2.1.0
  - flatbuffers==2.0.7
  - cymem==2.0.6
  - preshed==2.0.1
  - markupsafe==2.0.1
  - azure-mgmt-authorization==2.0.0
  - argcomplete==2.0.0
  - googleapis-common-protos==1.56.4
  - azureml-automl-runtime==1.45.0
  - azureml-core==1.45.0
  - azureml-train-automl-client==1.45.0
  - azureml-dataset-runtime==1.45.0
  - azureml-training-tabular==1.45.0
  - azureml-train-restclients-hyperdrive==1.45.0
  - azureml-automl-core==1.45.0
  - azureml-pipeline-core==1.45.0
  - azureml-train-core==1.45.0
  - azureml-mlflow==1.45.0
  - azureml-responsibleai==1.45.0
  - azureml-telemetry==1.45.0
  - mlflow-skinny==1.28.0
  - urllib3==1.26.12
  - azure-core==1.25.1
  - numpy==1.21.6
  - botocore==1.18.18
  - msal==1.18.0
  - six==1.16.0
  - boto3==1.15.18
  - cffi==1.15.1
  - wrapt==1.12.1
  - onnx==1.12.0
  - onnxruntime==1.11.1
  - sympy==1.10.1
  - azure-identity==1.10.0
  - smart-open==1.9.0
  - pkginfo==1.8.3
  - nimbusml==1.8.0
  - pmdarima==1.7.1
  - pysocks==1.7.1
  - sklearn-pandas==1.7.0
  - distro==1.7.0
  - tblib==1.7.0
  - debugpy==1.6.3
  - onnxconverter-common==1.6.0
  - keras2onnx==1.6.0
  - nest-asyncio==1.5.5
  - scipy==1.5.3
  - pynacl==1.5.0
  - skl2onnx==1.4.9
  - kiwisolver==1.4.4
  - pydot==1.4.2
  - onnxmltools==1.4.1
  - websocket-client==1.4.1
  - torch==1.4.0
  - pkgutil-resolve-name==1.3.10
  - xgboost==1.3.3
  - azure-mgmt-core==1.3.2
  - requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
  - partd==1.3.0
  - adal==1.2.7
  - mpmath==1.2.1
  - setuptools-git==1.2
  - azure-common==1.1.28
  - opencensus-ext-azure==1.1.7
  - pandas==1.1.5
  - termcolor==1.1.0
  - joblib==1.1.0
  - murmurhash==1.0.8
  - srsly==1.0.5
  - msgpack==1.0.4
  - heapdict==1.0.1
  - jmespath==1.0.1
  - azureml-model-management-sdk==1.0.1b6.post1
  - backports.weakref==1.0.post1
  - pytorch-transformers==1.0.0
  - backports.tempfile==1.0
  - locket==1.0.0
  - msal-extensions==1.0.0
  - azure-graphrbac==0.61.1
  - numba==0.55.2
  - shap==0.39.0
  - llvmlite==0.38.1
  - wheel==0.37.1
  - cython==0.29.32
  - interpret-community==0.26.0
  - scikit-learn==0.22.1
  - responsibleai==0.21.0
  - horovod==0.19.4
  - jedi==0.18.1
  - pyrsistent==0.18.1
  - databricks-cli==0.17.3
  - econml==0.13.1
  - sparse==0.13.0
  - toolz==0.12.0
  - applicationinsights==0.11.10
  - statsmodels==0.11.1
  - cycler==0.11.0
  - opencensus==0.11.0
  - holidays==0.10.3
  - pathspec==0.10.1
  - wasabi==0.10.1
  - plac==0.9.6
  - cmdstanpy==0.9.5
  - knack==0.9.0
  - tabulate==0.8.10
  - parso==0.8.3
  - jeepney==0.8.0
  - dice-ml==0.8
  - azureml-inference-server-http==0.7.5
  - pickleshare==0.7.5
  - fbprophet==0.7.1
  - dowhy==0.7.1
  - msrest==0.7.1
  - fairlearn==0.7.0
  - ptyprocess==0.7.0
  - msrestazure==0.6.4
  - isodate==0.6.1
  - dataclasses==0.6
  - pymeeus==0.5.11
  - patsy==0.5.2
  - ndg-httpsclient==0.5.1
  - pyasn1==0.4.8
  - sqlparse==0.4.2
  - entrypoints==0.4
  - fire==0.4.0
  - erroranalysis==0.3.9
  - s3transfer==0.3.7
  - dill==0.3.5.1
  - pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
  - interpret-core==0.2.7
  - wcwidth==0.2.5
  - blis==0.2.4
  - korean-lunar-calendar==0.2.1
  - backcall==0.2.0
  - raiutils==0.2.0
  - ml-wrappers==0.2.0
  - json-logging-py==0.2
  - sentencepiece==0.1.97
  - matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
  - opencensus-context==0.1.3
  - lunarcalendar==0.0.9
  - slicer==0.0.7
  - azureml-train-automl-runtime==1.45.0
  - inference-schema
  - azureml-interpret==1.45.0
  - azureml-defaults==1.45.0
- numpy~=1.21.6
- scikit-learn==0.22.1
- pandas~=1.1.5
- holidays==0.10.3
- setuptools-git
- pytorch=1.4.0
- cudatoolkit=10.0.130
- psutil>5.0.0,<6.0.0
- numpy==1.21.6
- pandas==1.1.5
- py-xgboost<=1.3.3
- fbprophet==0.7.1
- psutil==5.9.0
name: project_environment

```

Now my question is: what is the best way to load the environment of the model with it instead of using another environement?

Thank you.
````

Answer (score 0):

The version of python which was auto used in the model generation is the major issue here. Check the current working python version of the model in the conda.yml file as mentioned below.

[image]

The model which currently worked was on 3.7.9.
But in the notebook, the version will be different.

[image]

Deprecate the version of the notebook or upgrade the python version in conda.yml file and register the model.

```
import joblib
from azureml.core.model import Model
from azureml.core import Workspace
import os
import pickle

ws = Workspace.from_config()
path=Model.get_model_path('my_automl_model', version=1, _workspace=ws)
model_path = os.path.join(path, 'model.pkl')
model = joblib.load(model_path)
```

the above code will run with the change of python running version. As model is already created, it’s required to deprecate the default version of python in notebook.